# How to make this numpy code faster?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop

```
import numpy as np
w_array=np.random.rand(120,10)
w = 1
for i in xrange(100):
    if i==3:
        w*=w_array[i,5]
    else:
        w *= (1 - w_array[i, :5 + 1].sum())
```

How can I make this code faster?

Comment: Your question is probably more suited to Code Review SE: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd love to try to help you, but you need to make a self-contained example. Give us a sample `w_array`.

Comment: `codereview` is not good for `numpy` performance questions.  `vectorization` questions like this are common on SO.  @Yang, have you searched questions on how to replace iteration with operations on the whole array?  There are many.

Comment: @Will Sorry for that. It is the first question I ask here. I have edited the code.

Comment: @hpaulj I usually do not do optimization on codes, so I don't really know exactly what I can search before. Thank you for your patient reply. I will try to understand it and also search the key word you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I'll demonstrate how you can do something like this faster:

First an iteration:

```
In [3]: x=np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)

In [4]: for i in range(5):
   ...:     if i==3:
   ...:         print(x[i,:])
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print(x[i,:].sum())
   ...:         
1
5
9
[6 7]
17
```

Generate the same values without iteration:

```
In [9]: x[3,:]
Out[9]: array([6, 7])

In [10]: x[np.arange(5)!=3,:].sum(1)
Out[10]: array([ 1,  5,  9, 17])
```

Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: Indexation via a Boolean array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I am really interested in this kind of tricks. Are there any books or other references talking about these tricks?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from @hpaulj, I've tested the following codes. It seems that it improves a lot.. Many thanks!

```
import numpy as np
w_array = np.random.rand(120, 10)
def program1(w_array):
    w = 1
    for i in xrange(100):
        if i == 3:
            w *= w_array[i, 5]
        else:
            w *= (1 - w_array[i, :5 + 1].sum())
    return w

def program2(w_array):
    w_array=w_array[:100,:]
    return w_array[3,5]*((1-w_array[np.arange(100)!=3,:5+1].sum(1)).prod())

%timeit result1=program1(w_array)
1000 loops, best of 3: 202 µs per loop
%timeit result2=program2(w_array)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.2 µs per loop
```